# I get a number when I run the follwing MDX in my SSAS cube . Can someone enlighten me on what happens and why when I run this?

Tags: mdx

I keep getting a number when I run the following query, not sure what it means or how I am getting a number. Hoping someone can satisfy my curiosity.

SELECT FROM [MyCube]

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a number for default measure in the cube. So when you don't specify any measure in the query it will show value for the default measure.